# iSeries stored procedure - how to get handle on the spool file output?

Tags: stored-procedures, ibm-midrange, rpgle

We have a stored procedure written using a CL and RPG program combination. When called locally on the iSeries all is fine. When called externally (for example from a SQL frontend) the RPG program cannot get a hadle on the spool file it produces because the spool file appears under a different (random?) job number and user. 
The jobs run as QUSER in the QUSRWRK subsystem but the spool file gets the user id of which the connection was made externally in the connection pool (i.e USERA).

Is there a way of being able reliably to get a handle on the correct sppol file as the job runs (rather than relying on picking the last spool fiel from that queue etc).

Answer (score 1):

If you're running a stored procedure (running in job QZDASOINIT), you will no be able to access the spooled output via the program status data structure. Those spooled files reside in a job named, user/QPRTJOB, where user is the "current user" running the stored procedure. To access the spooled files, run api QSPRILSP to obtain a structure that points you to the spooled file.

Both the behavior and API is well documented in IBM's infocenter.

Answer (score 1):

A server job (e.g., a database server instance for ODBC/JDBC) runs under a system user profile. For stored procs, the system user will usually be QUSER. Objects created within a job are usually owned by the job user.

Server jobs generally perform work **on behalf** of other users. You tell the server job which user when you establish a connection. (And note that during its lifetime a given server job might work on behalf of many different users.)

Particularly for spooled output, this is a problem because the spooling subsystem has been around longer than we've had the "Web" and before we had significant numbers of users connecting to remote databases. The behavior of switching around from user to user simply isn't part of the spooling subsystem's makeup, nor can a vendor such as IBM determine when a spooled file should be owned by a particular job user or connection user. (And spooling is not a major element of database connections.)

IBM did adapt how spooling is associated output with users by defaulting "switched users" output to collect in [**a job named QPRTJOB**](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/rzalu/rzaluqprtjob.htm), but it doesn't quite fit with how you want a later RPG program to handle the output.

However, if you create a stored proc that generates spooled output, the proc can choose who owns the output and thereby choose to keep it within the same job. Consider these example CALLs that can be be pasted into the iSeries Navigator 'Run SQL Scripts' function:

```
call qsys2.qcmdexc ('OVRPRTF FILE(*PRTF) SPLFOWN(*JOB) OVRSCOPE(*JOB)' , 48);
call qsys2.qcmdexc ('DSPMSGD RANGE(CPF9899) MSGF(QCPFMSG) OUTPUT(*PRINT)' , 51);
call qsys2.qcmdexc ('DLTOVR FILE(*PRTF) LVL(*JOB)' , 28);
```

If you run them as a set, they create spooled output showing the attributes of the message description for CPF9899. If you check afterwards, you should see that QUSER now owns a spooled file named QPMSGD and that it resides within the QZDASOINIT job that's handling your remote database requests. A RPG program within that job can easily find the "*LAST" spooled file in that case. Also, if you delete the first and last CALL and now run just the middle one, you should find that you own the next spooled file.

(QUSER is the IBM default. If your system uses a different user profile, substitute that user for "QUSER".)

**Recommendation:**

Change your SP to issue an appropriate OVRPRTF command before spooling output that you need to capture in the job and to issue DLTOVR after the output is generated.

You might use commands similar to the ones shown here to create a test procedure. Experiment with different OVRSCOPE() settings and with FILE(*PRTF) or with specifically named files. Also, create output before and after the override commands to see how differently they behave.

Stay aware that the server job might handle a different user after your SP finishes (or a different SP might be called later in the job), so you'll want to be sure that DLTOVR runs. (That's one reason to keep it close to the OVRPRTF.)

Answer (score 0):

I need a bit more information, but I'll make some assumptions. Please clarify if I assumed wrong.

The QUSER in QUSRWRK behavior is correct. You are now running through the SQL server (or similar server). All connections run under these settings.

There are a couple approaches.

1) Assuming that this all runs in one job. Using '*" for the job information should work.

2) The other option is to use RTVJOBA CURUSER(&ME). The current user is the person that is logged in. USER would not work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify the RPG program you can retrieve job information from the [Program Status Data Structure](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/iseries/v5r1/ic2924/books/c092508381.htm) while the [File Information Data Structure](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/iseries/v5r1/ic2924/books/c092508378.htm) has the spool file number from the open feedback area.  However I'm not sure the job information will be for the QUSER job (not what you need) or for the USERA job (what you need).  The spool file number could be enough of a handle for subsequent [Print API](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/apis/print1.htm) calls.

Answer (score 0):

The job itself knows or can find out (see previous answers) so, if all else fails, modify the program to place a message on a queue that provides the information you need. Read it off at your leisure.

.